# Answer edited to add another solution while overwriting the previous accepted solution

Tags: discussion, edits, answers, accepted-answer

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26271591/angularjs-ngrepeat-how-to-differentiate-even-odd-elements/26271734#26271734) is my answer to a question, well, it used to be until the edit.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/26271734/revisions) is the edit history for my answer. I just opened StackOverflow and I saw some users(Users - [Community](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) and [Dawson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/608924/dawson)) has edited my answer to a answer of their own **while my answer is also a correct one**.

When those users had an answer to the question, shouldn't they

- post their answer as a different answer instead of overwriting
  mine??
- have added their solutions as suggestions in comments to my answer??
- have at least appended their answers to my answer instead of overwriting mine??

**I just need my answer back there and their answers posted as a new one.**

Comment: This should be asked on MSO, but briefly: just rollback to the revision you want. Maybe also flag for moderator attention if you think Dawson is routinely approving terrible edits by anonymous users (like this).

Comment: True, this is rude and abuse of the edit feature, worth a flag and official moderator warning for the offending user (or suspension, if he did it before and was warned already). If you didn't flag yet, please go ahead and do it now.

Comment: @Nathan why MSO? This can happen in any SE site. (Radical change of answer)